# Why is ajaxStart not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use ajax to create a loading screen, while the JavaScript loads, however the ajaxStart() function doesn't seem to be working. 
Here is the code that I am currently trying to get working.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  console.log("started");
});
```

Comment: What you have shown works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/kd8cbj3z/. You will need to provide an [mcve] that reproduces issue

Comment: ajaxStart is a handler for the first ajax request from the page. https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/ It waits what happens later.

Comment: doc: If `$.ajax()` or `$.ajaxSetup()` is called with the `global` option set to `false`, the `.ajaxStart()` method will not fire.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't load via ajax, so that won't work.